On commutative $C^*$-algebras and compactifications
A C$^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra together with a norm $\|\cdot\|$ with respect to which $\mathcal{A}$ is complete and the norm is submultiplicative ($\|xy\|\leq \|x\|\|y\|$). Furthermore, $\mathcal{A}$ is equipped with an involution $^*$ such that $$\|xx^*\|=\|x\|^2.$$
The last identity is the so called C$^*$-identity and is the magical condition that differentiates C$^*$-algebras from Banach algebras.
It is well-known (Gelfand representation) that any commutative C$^*$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is $^*$-isomorphic to $C_0(X)$ where $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space. Moreover, $\mathcal{A}$ is unital if and only if $X$ can be chosen as a compact Hausdorff space.
Now consider the C$^*$-algebra $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ of bounded continuous functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$. The norm is given by $$\|f\|=\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)|$$ and involution is given by $f^*(x)=\overline{f(x)}$. By the Gelfand representation, $C_b(\mathbb{R})\cong C_0(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$ as $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is unital. In fact, one can take $X=\beta \mathbb{R}$ where $\beta \mathbb{R}$ is the Stone-Čech compacitifcation or the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.
Consider now the subspace $C_e(\mathbb{R})\subseteq C_b(\mathbb{R})$ given by $$f\in C_e(\mathbb{R})\Leftrightarrow \exists L\in \mathbb{C}: \lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x)=L.$$
So $f$ belongs to $C_e(\mathbb{R})$ if both limits at infinity are equal, or put differently, $f\in C_e(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $f$ is of the form $g+\lambda \mathbf{1}$ for some $g\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lambda=\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}f(x)\in \mathbb{C}$. It seems pretty clear that $C_e(\mathbb{R})$ is itself a C$^*$-algebra (unless I missed something here?) and clearly this is unital and commutative. Hence the Gelfand representation states that $C_e(\mathbb{R})\cong C_0(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$.
It's also pretty clear that this particular $X$ has to be a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. As I can't really imagine anything smaller than a one-point compactification, I guess that $X\cong \beta \mathbb{R}$. In other words, $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ should also be $^*$-isomorphic to $C_e(\mathbb{R})$. I don't immediately see an obvious isomorphism, so here are my questions;

Are $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ and $C_e(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic as C$^*$-algebras?
Can you explicitly write down an isomorphism?
If the answer to the first question is no, then what compactification lives between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta\mathbb{R}$? What then distinguishes the underlying topological spaces?

Finally I should mention that I purely ask these questions for fun without any deep knowledge about C$^*$-algebras. I'm just a math-hobbyist and it's been 4 years since I worked in mathematics and over 10 years since I last read about C$^*$-algebras. These questions randomly popped into my mind and I couldn't intuitively answer it.

Most of the things you wrote down are correct, except one: Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ and one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ are very different things. The former is not metrizable and has cardinality (if I’m not misremembering) $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$, while the latter is homeomorphic to $S^1$. $C_b(\mathbb{R}) = C_0(\beta\mathbb{R})$ and $C_e(\mathbb{R}) = C_0(\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\})$, where $\beta\mathbb{R}$ is the Stone-Čech compactification and $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ is the one-point compactification, are both correct, but the fact I mentioned above means they’re not isomorphic $C^\ast$-algebras. (More directly, $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ is non-separable while $C_e(\mathbb{R})$ is separable.)

For the final question of what compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$ there are, just to formalize, we’ll call $X$ a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ if $X$ is compact Hausdorff and there is an open topological embedding $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow X$ whose range is dense. Then any compactification of $X$ sits between $\beta\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, in the sense that there are surjective continuous maps $\beta\mathbb{R} \to X \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ which restrict to identity maps on $\mathbb{R}$. Their continuous function algebras then sit between $C_e(\mathbb{R})$ and $C_b(\mathbb{R})$ - in fact, any $C^\ast$-algebra intermediate between the two corresponds to a compactification. There are plenty of examples apart from just one-point and Stone-Čech compactifications. Say, the subalgebra of bounded continuous functions with limits both at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, but the two limits may not be equal, corresponds to the two-point compactification (i.e., the extended real line) $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}$. The subalgebra consisting of $f + g$ where $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $g$ is periodic of period $1$ corresponds to a compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ which is $\mathbb{R}$ adjoining a circle $S^1$, etc.

A side remark: given the way the OP has written the question, I’m not sure if the OP is aware of this or not, but given a commutative $C^\ast$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$, the locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ s.t. $\mathcal{A} \simeq C_0(X)$ is unique, up to homeomorphism, so you don’t need to say $X$ can be “chosen” to have some properties.

Oh great. I probably should read up about the Stone-Cech compactification, clearly I had the wrong idea about it.
It absolutely makes sense that $C_e(\mathbb{R})$ corresponds to the one-point compactification and similarly about the two-point compactification. I must have misread about $C_b(\mathbb{R})$, nice to see non-seperableness come into play.

I am somewhat aware off the uniqueness of $X$, though if you drop local compactness, other topological spaces can still produce the same algebra. That’s why my wording was a bit more open.

@Mathematician42 That’s true, yeah, the uniqueness only applies when $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff.
